# Copy sheet from add-in workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make an add-in to make the work of some of my coworkers a little easier using a few macros I have created. One thing this add-in also contains is a phone book sheet that I would like to be able to add in as a new sheet at the end of their active workbook. I'm fairly new to VBA so I'm struggling with figuring out how to properly do this. I have a dialog box that asks yes or no to adding it in, so far what I have is:

```
Private Sub yes_Click()
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook

wb.Sheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)).name = "Phone Book"

Workbooks("Add-In.xlam").Sheets("phone").Activate
Cells.Copy
mainWB.Sheets("Phone Book").Range("A1").Paste

Unload Me
End Sub
```

I've tried a bunch of things, so this code may look a little like Frankenstein's monster. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Phone Book").Copy _
           After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
```

...assuming this code is running in your add-in.

Comment: Worked wonderfully! I was clearly overthinking it. Thanks a lot